# Cant delete persistent damaged application Bluestack

Tags: permission, macos

I uninstalled BlueStacks as it was unused application, and it persists as a broken application and I can't delete it.

I've tried to `sudo rm -rf` but it said operation not permitted.

> [image: Broken Apps Cant be deleted]
>
> [image: Operation cannot be permitted on terminal]

Is there any way i can delete it cleanly?

Comment: Please use copy/paste instead of screenshots for Terminal output to make text accessible to the search function and to people relying on screen readers.

Comment: Anyway, why is the application installed in `/Library/StagedExtensions`? Even https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000739232-How-can-I-uninstall-BlueStacks-from-my-Mac- implies that is should have been installed in `/Applications`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to boot the Mac in Recovery Mode (hold Cmd + R when rebooting), open a Terminal and run the command below. This will allow you to remove the rest of the app.

```
rm -rf /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Library/StagedExtensions/Applications/BlueStacks.app
```

The reason is that when you install Bluestacks, you install not only the app itself, but also a kernel extension that is stored in /Library/StagedExtensions. You give specific permission to install that extension.

However, when it comes to uninstalling - as Bluestacks doesn't provider a full uninstaller - you'll have to do it manually. Unfortunately SIP protects the kernel extensions from alteration when booted in standard mode. By rebooting in Recovery Mode (or disabling SIP), you can delete the files.

If you need, you can follow a more thorough how-to on how to reboot in Recovery Mode and remove the kernel extension here:

https://eclecticlight.co/2018/01/02/the-app-you-cant-trash-how-sip-is-broken-in-high-sierra/

Comment: RE: "open a Terminal and run the same command there"...  Running the same command will do nothing in macOS Recovery! One needs to change the path appropriately, e.g.: `rm -r /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Library/StagedExtensions/Applications/BlueStacks.app`

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks - the correct path was also in the link in my answer - I have updated with the correct path!

Comment: I didn't read the linked article as I'm well versed in deleting from macOS Recovery, however relevant information in links should always be included in the answers as links can become broken.

Comment: Well, I’m quite well versed in that too, but it’s not really the sole purpose of the article. It is specific for Bluestacks. The answe did include the relevant information, and did not rely on the link...

Comment: RE: "The answe did include the relevant information, and did not rely on the link" Before I posted my first comment, your OP stated "open a Terminal and run the same command there", so how is that including the relevant information when the `/Library/StagedExtensions` directory doesn't even exist when booted to macOS Recovery!? Had you not included the link and the person asking the question not read it, they'd be getting an error message while trying to "run the same command there"!

Comment: The real answer to the question is simple... Boot to macOS Recovery and in Terminal run the following command `rm -r /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Library/StagedExtensions/Applications/BlueStacks.app` and reboot. That's it, nothing else really matters and all the fluff isn't going to fix the issue. It wasn't till you made the edit after my first comment that your answer could stand on it's own self-contained information. Prior to my first comment one would have had to read the linked article to know the proper path to delete from!

Comment: I don’t know what your problem is, but I think you need to sort that out yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to clear the files, without the reboot, using:

```
sudo kextcache --clear-staging
```

Source: [this SO Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46535279/what-is-library-stagedextensions-for-and-how-to-remove-extensions). (Adding here to improve visibility.)

Comment: Why does this apply to BlueSTacks

Comment: It's not specific to BlueStacks, but the OP was having an issue with the app extensions in the StagedExtensions area, which can be removed using kextcache.

Comment: Ah as it is an image I did not spot that